# java arraylist changes value as i add value to it using an instance class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an instance class called Review that takes in String, String, int, String, boolean.

every time user inputs values for all 5 of those, it adds to an arrayList in the main. 
my problem here is that when the user updates the values, it also changes the values inside the arraylist that in the end, all the Review inside the arraylist turns out to be the same. I do not have anything static in the Review class. how can i fix this problem?

```
public class Review implements Comparable<Review>{
  private String reviewer;
  private String restaurant;
  private int rating;
  private String comment;
  private boolean recommended;
  public Review( String revName, String restName, int rating, String comment, boolean recommended) {
    reviewer = revName;
    restaurant = restName;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.recommended = recommended; 
  }
```

this is the basic class w/ constructor, they all have their own getter & setter.

```
private ArrayList<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();

Review review = new Review(revName, restName, rating, comment, recommended);

public void setReviews(Review review){
  reviews.add(review);
}
public ArrayList<Review> getReviews(){
    return reviews;
}
```

this is another class for importing and exporting.(i will call this "reader" class from now on)

in the main i just use

```
    ArrayList<Review> reviews = reader.getReviews();
```

to set them equal to each other every time there's an update

```
    reader.setReviews(review);
```

this is used after all 5 inputs by the user. user uses setters for individual variables from Review class to set the values.

Comment: You are probably using references wrongly. Post some code.

Comment: Where do you call the `setReviews` method?

Comment: there are 3 total classes, Review, main, and import/export. the import/export has the whole source of the arraylist. it is the origin of the arraylist so that i put data into the class anytime the values are updated, then call the arraylist back to the main class.

Comment: Please include the code where you *use* the `setReviews` method.

Comment: You should trace how many times you call `new Review(...)`.  If it's not in a loop, then only one object will have been created!

Comment: The code you've added has no indication of the use of `setReviews`. Please include the code that **uses** `setReviews`.

Comment: And please show us the **WHOLE LOOP**. Not just the line!

Comment: i'm really sorry that my descriptions aren't good enough. but Mark's comment helped me understand why this was happening. Again, I apologize for not providing all the necessary info for this.. Thank you so much for help guys. I tries to keep it simple as possible since the whole loop is more than 100 lines and seemed to be really unnecessary.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, it explains the exact same concept. Just mark it as correct so people stop looking at it. And it also gives you some coding tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your issue

When you declare this:

```
Object o = new Object();
```

the value that you work with, is the *pointer* to that object. Not the object itself. So when you're intending on adding several objects to an `ArrayList`, you're not adding the objects themselves. You're simply adding `pointers` to those objects. Hence, you need a new object for each item in the `ArrayList`. Why?

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
SomeClass a = s;

a.setName("Hello"); // Sets the object's name value that a points to.
s.getName(); // Will return "Hello".
```

This is because `a` and `s` both *point to the same object*.

### Other stuff

**Your constructor**

One of the key elements of readable code is consistency. If you do something one way, always do it that way if it doesn't impact the program's functionality. One example of where you don't follow that principle is here:

```
reviewer = revName;
restaurant = restName;
```

And the rest of the constructor looks like this:

```
this.rating = rating;
this.comment = comment;
this.recommended = recommended;
```

The latter part is the more commonly used code for a constructor, and I would recommend changing the first part, so that it fits with the pattern, ie:

```
this.reviewer = reviewer;
this.restaurant = restaurant;
```

**An object declaration**

```
Review review = new Review(revName, restName, rating, comment, recommended);
```

I really don't know what this code is for, or at least, it's not obvious from the code you've provided.